# Displaying posts from custom post type and sorting them by starting time custom field, grouping them by day

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, advanced-custom-fields

I have html template from which I have to create custom Wordpress theme - I am using mostly advanced custom fields and I need to disply posts in a manner that I explained in the title (Displaying posts from custom post type and sorting them by starting time custom field, grouping them by day). Here's image with how posts would actually look.
[here's the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD4cD.png)

Here are my defined fields. [defined custom fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHXBh.png)

So if I have 3 workshops on Monday they would show under Monday and would sort by starting time with earliest first. For workshop speaker/s I am using relationship field that lets me add one or more speaker (also custom post type) to workshop custom post type (which I haven't figured out yet but I will).

I have notion about sorting - something like `$arrayname[date][startingtime] = array(all the data that needs to be displayed)` but I have 0 idea on how to implement it in actual query that pulls Workshops (maybe something with foreach loop?).

So basically this is code I have now and how far I've gotten before getting stuck.

```
<?php 

$args = array('post_type' => 'workshop');

$workshoptime = the_field('time');
$yeardate = the_field('workshop_date');

$sorting = array(
  array('time' => '$workshoptime'), 
  array('yearmonthdate' => '$yeardate'),
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

//Display the contents
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

?>

            <!--Tabs Box-->
            <div class="tabs-box">

                <!--Tab / Current / Monday-->
                <div class="tab current" id="monday">

                    <div class="hour-box active-box">
                        <div class="hour">10:00 AM</div>
                        <div class="img-circle circle"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="toggle-btn active"><h3><?php the_title();?></h3></div>
                        <div class="content-box collapsed">
                            <div class="content"><p><?php the_content();?></p></div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row professional clearfix">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 info">
                                    <figure class="img-circle image"><img class="img-circle" src="images/resource/testi-thumb-1.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                    <h5 class="prof-title"></h5>
                                    <h6 class="prof-occup">Speaker</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-right">

                                    <a href="#" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right dull">10:00 - 12:00</a>
                                    <a href="single-event.html" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>DETAILS ABOUT THE EVENT</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the items with `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,       
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value_datetime',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'meta_type'        => 'DATETIME',
    'meta_key'         => 'workshop_date',      
    'post_type'        => 'workshop',       
    'post_status'      => 'publish'     
);
```

Now you have the correct order in the loop.

Grouping by could look like:

```
// in loop
$timestamp = strtotime( $workshop_date );
$date = date( 'Y-m-d', $timestamp );

if ( $date == $current_date ) {
    // it is the same day
} else {
    // it is a new day
    $current_date = $date;
}
```

Comment: Maybe (but I don't know) it's better to use datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the grouping within your PHP script (looping through the post, you can detect when the date changes, and output the appropriate section header / footer).  In order to do that, you need to have your post sorted by date then time, which can be achieved with a regular WP_Query, but you need to use the meta_query feature for which the documentation is not super clear.

Here is a simple example:

```
<?php

$args = [
    'post_type' => 'workshop',
    'meta_query' => [
        'workshop_date' => [
            'key' => 'workshop_date', 
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ],
        'workshop_time' => [
            'key' => 'workshop_time', 
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ]
    ], 
    'orderby' => [
        'workshop_date' => 'ASC',
        'workshop_time' => 'ASC'
    ]
];
$loop = new WP_Query($args);


function print_workshop() {
?>
    <section class="workshop">
        <?php the_title() ?> at <?php the_field('workshop_time') ?>
    </section>
<?php
}

function print_day_header() {
?>
<article>
    <header><?php the_field('workshop_date') ?></header>
<?php
}

function print_day_footer() {
?>
</article>
<?php
}

$curday = false;
if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

if($curday !== get_field('workshop_date')) {
    // start a new day
    if($curday) {
        print_day_footer();
    }
    print_day_header();
    $curday = get_field('workshop_date');
}
// content
print_workshop();

endwhile; 

// close the last one
print_day_footer();

else : ?>

<article id="post-not-found" class="hentry cf">
    Text for no workshop found
</article>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This yields the following HTML:

```
<article>
    <header>06/10/2016</header>
    <section class="workshop">
        Workshop on the 6th at 11:00    </section>
</article>
<article>
    <header>13/10/2016</header>
    <section class="workshop">
        Workshop before the others on the 13th at 08:00    </section>
    <section class="workshop">
        Workshop 1 at 10:00    </section>
    <section class="workshop">
        Workshop 2, same day at 12:00    </section>
</article>
<article>
    <header>14/10/2016</header>
    <section class="workshop">
        Workshop 3, next day at 10:00    </section>
</article>
<article>
    <header>01/11/2016</header>
    <section class="workshop">
        A workshop in November at 09:00    </section>
</article>
```

One last thing - if you have your time stored as text in the database, store it in a normalized fashion (i.e., "13:00", not "1 pm"), otherwise it won't sort properly.  You can do that with ACF.  ACF will already take care of that for the date field, so you don't have to worry about that one, only the time.

Hope this helps!